# Recurring HDD failures

Tags: linux, hard-drive, hardware-failure

My Debian linux home computer has 3 HDDs :
- 1 for my Debian installation (primary 250GB HDD) using EXT4
- another for Windows (rarely used)
- another which is a clone of the Debian one and is used exclusively as a backup

To this day, I have bought 3 new 500GB 2.5 Inch Internal HDDs and 1 32GB SSD to replace the Debian clone HDD. They break every 1 to 4 months approximately. The backup is done just once a week and consists of copying a single 5GB folder containing 15,000 files. (The other 2 HDDs have never been replaced/broken.) My computer is on 24/7 using the primary Debian 250GB HDD and never has a problem happened. I've bought from different brands: Samsung, Seagate, and Western Digital.

What is going on ?

**EDIT 1**
- All 4 drives have failed (including the SSD).
- The drives no longer appear in the BIOS screen. fdisk cannot locate the drive either. (I have not opened the CPU box nor have I even touched the HDDs.)

**EDIT 2**
- I replaced the HDD's cable and the BIOS still does not locate the drive.
- I did not RMA any drive

Comment: What are the exact symptoms of the failures? Has the SSD failed?

Comment: If they don't show up in BIOS at all, it is more likely to be a power or cabling issue rather than the disks has actually failed.

Comment: i'd try popping the drives in another system to be sure. Did you RMA any of the dead drives at any point?

Comment: What kind of wattage is your power supply rated for?

Comment: hm, then we can't rule out anything.  From the drives 'working' on USB, i'd suspect your motherboard or Power supply

Comment: @techie007 It is 350W. I use an energy efficient X2 AMD chip which I think was either 45 or 65 TDP. I also use the built-in graphics card so total watt usage must be well below 350.

Comment: 2 HDDs and/or a video card can overdraw a 350W on a current Core i5 system.  If the drives are OK in another system, then you are describing an under-power situation.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I have to assume that these are SATA drives.

The underpower situation can be tested in a very simple way:

1. Disconnect all drives from the power
2. Connect Single drive
3. Power Up the system.  See if the drive is seen.

If the drive is not seen then the issue is likely to be the controller.